# Поясните на пальцах этот код

Tags: java

Не могу понять как работает данный код. Поясните на пальцах, пожалуйста.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i >= 3) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Yuhu");
    if (i >= 1) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("Tata");
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Выводит:

```
 // Yuhu
 // Tata
 // Yuhu
 // Yuhu
 // 3
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что сразу выводит Yuhu Tata, но как он далее выводит два раза Yuhu?

Answer (score 8):

```
int i;
//цикл (выполняется 5 раз: i тут от 0 до 4)
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

//если шаг цикла больше или равен 3-м, то тогда цикл перестает выполняться
//break - `ломает` цикл
if (i >= 3) {
  break;
}

System.out.println("Yuhu");

//если шаг цикла больше или равен 1, то тогда мы переходим к началу цикла
//оператор continue возвращает цикл к началу выполнения 
if (i >= 1) {
  continue;
}
System.out.println("Tata");
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Вот как это выполнит компилятор (схематично):

```
0 шаг:
i = 0
i >= 3 //не выполнится
System.out.println("Yuhu");
i >= 1 //не выполнится
System.out.println("Tata");

1 шаг:
i = 1
i >= 3 //не выполнится
System.out.println("Yuhu");
i >= 1 { continue; } //выполнится
//переходим к началу цикла и пропускаем оставшееся тело цикла

2 шаг:
i = 2
i >= 3 //не выполнится
System.out.println("Yuhu");
i >= 1 { continue; } //выполнится
//переходим к началу цикла и пропускаем оставшееся тело цикла

3 шаг:
i = 3
i >= 3 { break; } //выполнится
//цикл остановится
```

Ну и в конце выводим на консоль `i`, который равен 3-м.

Answer (score 4):

1. При первой итерации ни одно из условий не верно и выводятся оба слова.
2. При второй и третьей итерациях второе условие верно и второе слово не выводится, т.к. цикл сразу переходит ко следующей итерации.
3. При 4 итерации первое условие верно, цикл завершается и печатается значение `i` после цикла

Answer (score 0):

Потому-что есть условие

```
if (i >= 1) {
     continue; }
```

Если i>=1 то все, что идет далее пропускается и запускается следующая итерация. Поэтому `System.out.println("Tata");` делается только 1 раз.